# Proof that the matrix multiplication is associative – is commutativity of the elements necessary?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a picture of the proof, we assume that the elements of the matrix are elements of a ring:

[image]

[image]

I don't know how the associativity is proved here without using commutativity.

I have changed the notation myself in order to understand the proof better:

$$d_{ji}=(a_{j1}b_{11}+...+a_{jn}b_{n1})c_{1i}+...+(a_{j1}b_{1l}+...+a_{jn}b_{nl})c_{li}$$

is because of distributivity

$$(a_{j1}b_{11}c_{1i}+...+a_{jn}b_{n1}c_{1i})+...+(a_{j1}b_{1l}c_{li}+...+a_{jn}b_{nl}c_{li})$$

which is because of associativity the same as

$$a_{j1}b_{11}c_{1i}+...+a_{jn}b_{n1}c_{1i}+...+a_{j1}b_{1l}c_{li}+...+a_{jn}b_{nl}c_{li}\tag{*}$$

which means I can put the parenthesis where I want.

I want to show that this is equal to: $a_{j1}(b_{11}c_{1i}+...+b_{1l}c_{li})+...+a_{jn}(b_{n1}c_{1i}+...+b_{nl}c_{li})$.

However, because of distributivity and associativity, this is equal to

$$a_{j1}b_{11}c_{1i}+...+a_{j1}b_{1l}c_{li}+...+a_{jn}b_{n1}c_{1i}+...+a_{jn}b_{nl}c_{li}\tag{**}$$

The array $(*)$ has a different order than the array $(**)$. Therefore the commutativity was used but the proof says only associativity and distributivity is used.

Is there a mistake in my reasoning or is commutativity unnecessary?

EDIT

Definiton of matrixmultiplication:

[image]

Comment: The confusion is due to equivocating between commutativity of addition and commutativity of multiplication. The former is such a harmless assumption that it is barely ever mentioned.

Comment: Consider multiplication of $1\!\times\!1$ matrices over a ring. The ring does not have to be commutative.

Comment: @somos If I have understood the first comment correctly then the commutativity of the addition is necessary for the general case. For $1\times 1$ matrices it is not necessary in order to prove the statement, but this is a special case.

Comment: The definition of a general ring requires associative multiplication and commutative addition, but **not** commutative multiplication. The $1\!\times\!1$ matrix case already demonstrates that commutative multiplication is not required for multiplication associativity.

Comment: commutative addition is also not required for this case

Comment: What does blk mean and where does it come from?

Answer (score 3):

Let $A = (A_{ij})$, $B = (B_{ij})$ and $C = (C_{ij})$ be matrices with the correct sizes to make all the relevant multiplications well-defined. Just compute $$((AB)C)_{ij} = \sum_k (AB)_{ik}C_{kj} = \sum_k \left(\sum_\ell A_{i\ell}B_{\ell k}\right)C_{kj} = \sum_{k,\ell} A_{i\ell}B_{\ell k}C_{kj}.$$On the other hand, we have $$(A(BC))_{ij} = \sum_\ell A_{i\ell} (BC)_{\ell j} = \sum_{\ell} A_{i\ell}\left(\sum_k B_{\ell k}C_{kj}\right) = \sum_{k,\ell}A_{i\ell}B_{\ell k}C_{kj}.$$The expressions are equal, and so we are done. We are not requiring that the entries of $A$, $B$ and $C$ commute. We are just using the distributive property (to bring all the summations signs out) and associativity between *elements*. Namely, that $A_{i\ell}(B_{\ell k}C_{kj}) = (A_{i\ell}B_{\ell k})C_{kj}$, and then we add those expressions over $k$ and $\ell$.

Comment: we are using that welldefined *matrixmultiplication* is distributive and not that the *ring-over-the-matrix-multiplication* is distributive?

Comment: We are using the distributive property on the ring. We don't have addition between matrices anywhere here.

Comment: You wrote $\sum_l$ instead of $\sum_{l=1}^{n}$. I.e. you already implicitly used commutativity of the ring, if you have defined the matrixmultiplication with a fixed order like we did (see edited post) then we cannot make this conclusion without assuming commutativity of the ringelements, right?

Comment: Switching $\sum_k \sum_\ell = \sum_\ell \sum_k$ is not commutativity, it is associativity. That's a very common misconception. It changes the order which we sum the products of the elements in the ring, but not the order these elements are multiplied.

Comment: No, you need commutativity **and** associativity of addition in order to interchange summation signs. But it's about addition, not about multiplication.

Comment: Yes, we're using commutativity of $+$. I took that for granted, as it is included in the definition of a ring.